# Find the largest number in a string [jquery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I'm getting this value being returned from the variable _text - `&nbsp;1 - 12&nbsp;of&nbsp;73&nbsp;Items`

The value being returned from the variable _text is always different.

I need to parse out the largest number (73).

Here's what I've attempted:

```
var _text = $('#find-page .items-box:first > .items:first-child').html();

var nums = [];
$('_text').each( function() { nums.push( $(this).val() ); });
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, nums);
console.log(nums);
```

This is returning 0, which isn't correct.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can match all the numbers then map them and find the max:

```js
var str = "1 - 12 of 73 Items";
var max = Math.max(...str.match(/\d+/g).map(Number));
console.log(max)
```

Comment: Why do we need the "..."?

Comment: @MarcWilk, `Math.max()` requires comma separated number but `map()` will give you an array, `...` will convert the array to comma separated number needed by `Math.max()`:)

Comment: That checks out. Got it!

Answer (score 0):

If the string is the same every time, it is as simple as a regular expression matching the pattern

```js
var str = " 1 - 12 of 73 Items"

console.log(str.match(/of\s(\d+)/)[1])
```

If it can be any numbers in a string

```js
    var str = " 123 456 890 90 33"

    console.log(Math.max(...str.match(/(\d+)/g).map(x=>+x)))
```